# Create multiple temp tables in stored procedure using Prepared queries not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, session-variables

**Setup**

- MySQL 5.7 or 5.6

In the Below Stored procedure what I'm trying to do is create a few Temp Tables.    Some of which are simple and static, and 2 of which are dynamic (TempQuery1, TempQuery2).

All temp tables are Built -> Prepared -> executed first.  Then the main query that utilizes the temp tables (GetQuery) is executed.

**Problem**

When executed exactly like it is on a fresh connection, I get

```
 Error Code: 1146. Table 'Job1111.TempPipeER' doesn't exist
```

Which lead me to think I had a typeo or something.. In testing I found that if I follow the next couple steps t works fine.

- Comment out Prepare and Execute for both Query2 and GetQuery
- Save the stored procedure and run it 2 times. (getting expected error from Deallocate)
- Uncomment out Query 2.
- Save the stored procedure and run it 2 more times. (getting expected error from Deallocate)
- Finally uncomment all Prepares and Executes
- Save and run stored procedure... NOW it works.

**Question**

- Why am I having to go through these step to let it build the temp tables one at a time.
- Does a following execute wait for previous to finish before starting?
- Is there a way to force the procedure to wait for an execute/ table build to finish?
- Is there a way to signal/echo/console.log() type of method that could be used to accurately show the completion of a temp table build and the start of an execute to prove that is even my real problem?

**Observation/Guess**

The way it is acting is like the Execute BuildGetQuery is executing before TempTable `Job1111`.`TempPipeER` is finished building.  And sine GetQuery utilizes the TempPipeER able in a Join.  The GetQuery fails.

But if I slowly build each table one at a time, then it works fine for the duration of that MySQL work bench session.

**Stored Procedure Create Statement**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Job1111`.`GetPipeStats`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`PSAAdmin`@`%` PROCEDURE `Job1111`.`GetPipeStats`( IN GroupedBy varchar(24))
BEGIN

### Declare Variables ###
DECLARE MechHoursPercent DECIMAL(3,2);
DECLARE TestingHoursPercent DECIMAL(3,2);
DECLARE CompleteForTestPercent DECIMAL(3,2);
DECLARE HydroHoursPercent DECIMAL(3,2);
DECLARE ClientTurnoverPercent DECIMAL(3,2);

### Set Variables ###
SELECT Value1 INTO MechHoursPercent
FROM `Job1111`.SETTINGS WHERE Label = "MechHoursPercent";
SELECT Value1 INTO TestingHoursPercent
FROM `Job1111`.SETTINGS WHERE Label = "TestingHoursPercent";
SELECT Value1 INTO CompleteForTestPercent
FROM `Job1111`.SETTINGS WHERE Label = "CompleteForTestPercent";
SELECT Value1 INTO HydroHoursPercent
FROM `Job1111`.SETTINGS WHERE Label = "HydroHoursPercent";
SELECT Value1 INTO ClientTurnoverPercent
FROM `Job1111`.SETTINGS WHERE Label = "ClientTurnoverPercent";





### Build Temp Table Queries ###
#DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Job1111`.`TempPipeER`, `Job1111`.`TempPipeERT`;

SET @TempQuery1 = CONCAT('
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `Job1111`.`TempPipeER`(
INDEX `TempPipeER1` (`ID` ASC)
)
SELECT ID, BidID,  
sum(EarnedErectionHours) AS EarnedErectionHours, 
sum(EarnedBoltUpHours) AS EarnedBoltUpHours, 
sum(EarnedWeldHours) AS EarnedWeldHours, 
sum(EarnedCutHours) AS EarnedCutHours, 
sum(EarnedTrimHours) AS EarnedTrimHours, 
sum(EarnedSupportHours) AS EarnedSupportHours, 
sum(EarnedDemoHours) AS EarnedDemoHours, 
sum(EarnedMiscHours) AS EarnedMiscHours, 
sum(InstalledFootage) AS InstalledFootage, 
sum(InstalledBoltUps) AS InstalledBoltUps, 
sum(InstalledWelds) AS InstalledWelds, 
sum(InstalledCuts) AS InstalledCuts, 
sum(InstalledTrim) AS InstalledTrim, 
sum(InstalledSupports) AS InstalledSupports, 
sum(InstalledMisc) AS InstalledMisc, 
sum(InstalledDemo) AS  InstalledDemo

                FROM(SELECT min(td.ID) AS ID,td.BidID,

IF( 
COALESCE(se.ErectionLengthSpool1,0) 
+ COALESCE(se.ErectionLengthSpool2,0) 
+ COALESCE(se.ErectionLengthSpool3,0) 
+ COALESCE(se.ErectionLengthSpool4,0) 
+ COALESCE(se.ErectionLengthSpool5,0) 
+ COALESCE(se.ErectionLengthSpool6,0)
+ COALESCE(sme.MiscQuantity,0)
+ sum(COALESCE(cse.InstalledQuantity,0)) > td.TakeOffQuantity, /*Is Installed Greater then TakeOff*/
/*TRUE*/ GREATEST(td.TakeOffQuantity - sum(COALESCE(cse.InstalledQuantity,0)),0) * (td.EstimatedHours * ' ,MechHoursPercent, ' / td.TakeOffQuantity),
/*FALSE*/
COALESCE((td.EstimatedHours*' ,MechHoursPercent, '/td.TakeOffQuantity) 
* (COALESCE(se.ErectionLengthSpool1,0) 
+ COALESCE(se.ErectionLengthSpool2,0) 
+ COALESCE(se.ErectionLengthSpool3,0) 
+ COALESCE(se.ErectionLengthSpool4,0) 
+ COALESCE(se.ErectionLengthSpool5,0) 
+ COALESCE(se.ErectionLengthSpool6,0) 
+ COALESCE(sme.MiscQuantity,0)),0)
) AS EarnedErectionHours,

IF(COALESCE(sb.BoltUpQuantity,0) + COALESCE(smb.MiscQuantity,0) + sum(COALESCE(csb.InstalledQuantity,0))
    > td.TakeOffQuantity,/*Is Installed Greater then TakeOff*/
    /*TRUE*/ GREATEST(td.TakeOffQuantity - sum(COALESCE(csb.InstalledQuantity,0)),0) * (td.EstimatedHours * ' ,MechHoursPercent, ' / td.TakeOffQuantity),
    /*FALSE*/ COALESCE((td.EstimatedHours*' ,MechHoursPercent, '/td.TakeOffQuantity) * (COALESCE(sb.BoltUpQuantity,0)+COALESCE(smb.MiscQuantity,0)), 0)
    ) AS EarnedBoltUpHours,

IF(COALESCE(sw.WeldPercentCompleted * .01,0) + COALESCE(smw.MiscQuantity,0) + sum(COALESCE(csw.InstalledQuantity * .01,0))
    > td.TakeOffQuantity,/*Is Installed Greater then TakeOff*/
    /*TRUE*/ GREATEST(td.TakeOffQuantity - sum(COALESCE(csw.InstalledQuantity,0)),0) * (td.EstimatedHours * ' ,MechHoursPercent, ' / td.TakeOffQuantity),
    /*FALSE*/ COALESCE((td.EstimatedHours*' ,MechHoursPercent, '/td.TakeOffQuantity) * (COALESCE(sw.WeldPercentCompleted * .01,0)+COALESCE(smw.MiscQuantity,0)),0)
    ) AS EarnedWeldHours,

IF(COALESCE(scut.WeldPercentCompleted * .01,0) + COALESCE(smc.MiscQuantity,0) + sum(COALESCE(csc.InstalledQuantity * .01,0))
    > td.TakeOffQuantity,/*Is Installed Greater then TakeOff*/
    /*TRUE*/ GREATEST(td.TakeOffQuantity - sum(COALESCE(csc.InstalledQuantity,0)),0) * (td.EstimatedHours * ' ,MechHoursPercent, ' / td.TakeOffQuantity),
    /*FALSE*/ COALESCE((td.EstimatedHours*' ,MechHoursPercent, '/td.TakeOffQuantity) * (COALESCE(scut.WeldPercentCompleted * .01,0)+COALESCE(smc.MiscQuantity,0)),0)
    ) AS EarnedCutHours,

IF(COALESCE(st.TrimQuantity,0) + COALESCE(smt.MiscQuantity,0) + sum(COALESCE(cst.InstalledQuantity,0))
    > td.TakeOffQuantity,/*Is Installed Greater then TakeOff*/
    /*TRUE*/ GREATEST(td.TakeOffQuantity - sum(COALESCE(cst.InstalledQuantity,0)),0) * (td.EstimatedHours * ' ,MechHoursPercent, ' / td.TakeOffQuantity),
    /*FALSE*/ COALESCE((td.EstimatedHours*' ,MechHoursPercent, '/td.TakeOffQuantity) * (COALESCE(st.TrimQuantity,0)+COALESCE(smt.MiscQuantity,0)),0)
    ) AS EarnedTrimHours,

IF(COALESCE(ssu.SupportInstalled,0) + COALESCE(smssu.MiscQuantity,0) + sum(COALESCE(cssu.InstalledQuantity,0))
    > td.TakeOffQuantity,/*Is Installed Greater then TakeOff*/
    /*TRUE*/ GREATEST(td.TakeOffQuantity - sum(COALESCE(cssu.InstalledQuantity,0)),0) * (td.EstimatedHours * ' ,MechHoursPercent, ' / td.TakeOffQuantity),
    /*FALSE*/ COALESCE((td.EstimatedHours*' ,MechHoursPercent, '/td.TakeOffQuantity)*(COALESCE(ssu.SupportInstalled,0)+COALESCE(smssu.MiscQuantity,0)),0)
    ) AS EarnedSupportHours,

IF(COALESCE(sde.DemoQuantity,0) + COALESCE(smd.MiscQuantity,0) + sum(COALESCE(csd.InstalledQuantity,0))
    > td.TakeOffQuantity,/*Is Installed Greater then TakeOff*/
    /*TRUE*/ GREATEST(td.TakeOffQuantity - sum(COALESCE(csd.InstalledQuantity,0)),0) * (td.EstimatedHours * ' ,MechHoursPercent, ' / td.TakeOffQuantity),
    /*FALSE*/ COALESCE((td.EstimatedHours/td.TakeOffQuantity) * (COALESCE(sde.DemoQuantity,0)+COALESCE(smd.MiscQuantity,0)),0)
    ) AS EarnedDemoHours,

IF(COALESCE(sm.MiscQuantity,0) + sum(COALESCE(csm.InstalledQuantity,0))
    > td.TakeOffQuantity,/*Is Installed Greater then TakeOff*/
    /*TRUE*/ GREATEST(td.TakeOffQuantity - sum(COALESCE(csm.InstalledQuantity,0)),0) * (td.EstimatedHours * ' ,MechHoursPercent, ' / td.TakeOffQuantity),
    /*FALSE*/ COALESCE((td.EstimatedHours*' ,MechHoursPercent, '/td.TakeOffQuantity) * COALESCE(sm.MiscQuantity,0),0)
    ) AS EarnedMiscHours,


sum(COALESCE(se.ErectionLengthSpool1,0) + COALESCE(se.ErectionLengthSpool2,0) + COALESCE(se.ErectionLengthSpool3,0) + COALESCE(se.ErectionLengthSpool4,0) + COALESCE(se.ErectionLengthSpool5,0) + COALESCE(se.ErectionLengthSpool6,0) + COALESCE(sme.MiscQuantity,0)) AS InstalledFootage,
sum(COALESCE(sb.BoltUpQuantity,0) + COALESCE(smb.MiscQuantity,0)) AS InstalledBoltUps, 
sum(COALESCE(sw.WeldPercentCompleted * .01,0) + COALESCE(smw.MiscQuantity,0)) AS InstalledWelds,
sum(COALESCE(scut.WeldPercentCompleted * .01,0) + COALESCE(smc.MiscQuantity,0)) AS InstalledCuts,
sum(COALESCE(st.TrimQuantity,0) + COALESCE(smt.MiscQuantity,0)) AS InstalledTrim,
sum(COALESCE(ssu.SupportInstalled,0) + COALESCE(smssu.MiscQuantity,0)) AS InstalledSupports,
sum(COALESCE(sm.MiscQuantity,0)) AS InstalledMisc,
sum(COALESCE(sde.DemoQuantity,0) + COALESCE(smd.MiscQuantity,0)) AS InstalledDemo


FROM `Job1111`.SubmissionStatus ss
    JOIN PSA.REF_ActivityTypes at
        ON at.ID = ss.ActivityType

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsErection se
        ON se.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 11 AND se.ErectionRework = 0

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsBoltUp sb
        ON sb.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 21 AND sb.BoltUpRework = 0

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsWeld sw
        ON sw.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 22 AND  sw.WeldRework = 0

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsWeld scut
        ON scut.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 23 AND scut.WeldRework = 0

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsTrim st
        ON st.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType IN (30,31,33,34,35,39) AND st.TrimRework = 0

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ssu.ID, COALESCE((ssu.SupportPercentCompleted * .01 * ssu.SupportQuantity),0) AS SupportInstalled
                FROM `Job1111`.SubsSupports ssu
                WHERE ssu.SupportRework = 0) ssu
        ON ssu.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 32     

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsDemo sde
        ON sde.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType IN (50,51,52,53,59)

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.`TempTrackerDetailsPipe`td
        ON td.BidID = ss.fk_BidIDAssigned

/* #### Begining of Misc activities assigned joins #### */  
    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsMisc sm
        ON sm.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 91 AND td.ECT != "D" AND td.PipingActivityType = "MISC"  AND sm.MiscRework = 0

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsMisc sme
        ON sme.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 91 AND td.PipingActivityType = "PE" AND sme.MiscRework = 0

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsMisc smb
        ON smb.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 91 AND td.PipingActivityType = "BU" AND smb.MiscRework = 0

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsMisc smw
        ON smw.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 91 AND td.PipingActivityType = "W" AND smw.MiscRework = 0

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsMisc smc
        ON smc.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 91 AND td.ECT != "D" AND td.PipingActivityType = "CUT" AND smc.MiscRework = 0

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsMisc smt
        ON smt.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 91 AND td.ECT = "T" AND td.PipingActivityType IN ("V","Plug","HpLp","Other","Blind") AND smt.MiscRework = 0

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsMisc smssu
        ON smssu.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 91 AND td.PipingActivityType = "S" AND smssu.MiscRework = 0

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsMisc smd
        ON smd.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 91 AND td.ECT = "D" AND smd.MiscRework = 0


/* #### Begining of Cumulative Past sums Calculation #### */    
    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSE` cse
        ON ss.ActivityType IN (11,91) AND ss.fk_BidIDAssigned = cse.fk_BidIDAssigned AND cse.PSAActivityID < ss.PSAActivityID

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSB` csb
        ON ss.ActivityType IN (21,91) AND ss.fk_BidIDAssigned = csb.fk_BidIDAssigned AND csb.PSAActivityID < ss.PSAActivityID

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSW` csw
        ON ss.ActivityType IN (22,91) AND ss.fk_BidIDAssigned = csw.fk_BidIDAssigned AND csw.PSAActivityID < ss.PSAActivityID

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSC` csc
        ON ss.ActivityType IN (23,91) AND ss.fk_BidIDAssigned = csc.fk_BidIDAssigned AND csc.PSAActivityID < ss.PSAActivityID

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.`TempPipeCST` cst
        ON ss.ActivityType IN (30,31,33,34,35,39,91) AND ss.fk_BidIDAssigned = cst.fk_BidIDAssigned AND cst.PSAActivityID < ss.PSAActivityID

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSSU` cssu
        ON ss.ActivityType IN (32,91) AND ss.fk_BidIDAssigned = cssu.fk_BidIDAssigned AND cssu.PSAActivityID < ss.PSAActivityID

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSD` csd
        ON ss.ActivityType IN (50,51,52,53,59,91) AND ss.fk_BidIDAssigned = csd.fk_BidIDAssigned AND csd.PSAActivityID < ss.PSAActivityID

    LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSM` csm
        ON ss.ActivityType = 91 AND ss.fk_BidIDAssigned = csm.fk_BidIDAssigned AND csm.PSAActivityID < ss.PSAActivityID


WHERE fk_ActivityStatus IN (5,12)
AND ss.ActivityType IN (10,11,20,21,22,23,30,31,32,33,34,35,39,50,51,52,53,59,90,91,93)
GROUP BY ss.PSAActivityID)er0
GROUP BY BidID
');

SET @TempQuery2 = CONCAT('
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `Job1111`.`TempPipeERT`(
INDEX `TempPipeERT1` (`ID` ASC)
)
SELECT min(td.ID) AS ID, td.BidID,

IF(
    (COALESCE(td.EstimatedHours,0)*' ,TestingHoursPercent, '*' ,CompleteForTestPercent, ' * sum(COALESCE(steR.InstalledReadyForTesting, 0)))
    > COALESCE(td.EstimatedHours,0)*' ,TestingHoursPercent, '*' ,CompleteForTestPercent, ',
    /*TRUE*/
    COALESCE(td.EstimatedHours,0)*' ,TestingHoursPercent, '*' ,CompleteForTestPercent, ',
    /*FALSE*/
    (COALESCE(td.EstimatedHours,0)*' ,TestingHoursPercent, '*' ,CompleteForTestPercent, ' * sum(COALESCE(steR.InstalledReadyForTesting, 0)))
) AS EarnedReadyForTestingHours,

IF(
    (COALESCE(td.EstimatedHours,0)*' ,TestingHoursPercent, '*' ,HydroHoursPercent, ' * sum(COALESCE(steH.InstalledHydro, 0)))
    > COALESCE(td.EstimatedHours,0)*' ,TestingHoursPercent, '*' ,HydroHoursPercent, ',
    /*TRUE*/
    COALESCE(td.EstimatedHours,0)*' ,TestingHoursPercent, '*' ,HydroHoursPercent, ',
    /*FALSE*/
    (COALESCE(td.EstimatedHours,0)*' ,TestingHoursPercent, '*' ,HydroHoursPercent, ' * sum(COALESCE(steH.InstalledHydro, 0)))
) AS EarnedHydroHours,

IF(
    (COALESCE(td.EstimatedHours,0)*' ,TestingHoursPercent, '*' ,ClientTurnoverPercent, ' * sum(COALESCE(steC.InstalledClientTurnover, 0))) 
    > COALESCE(td.EstimatedHours,0)*' ,TestingHoursPercent, '*' ,ClientTurnoverPercent, ',
    /*TRUE*/
    COALESCE(td.EstimatedHours,0)*' ,TestingHoursPercent, '*' ,ClientTurnoverPercent, ',
    /*FALSE*/
    (COALESCE(td.EstimatedHours,0)*' ,TestingHoursPercent, '*' ,ClientTurnoverPercent, ' * sum(COALESCE(steC.InstalledClientTurnover, 0))) 
) AS EarnedClientTurnoverHours

FROM `Job1111`.trackerDetails td

LEFT JOIN (SELECT ste.ActivityType, ste.TestingTestPackageNumber, 1 AS InstalledReadyForTesting
            FROM `Job1111`.SubsTesting ste
            JOIN `Job1111`.SubmissionStatus ss
                ON ss.ActivityRowId = ste.ID AND ss.ActivityType = 41 AND ss.fk_ActivityStatus IN (5,12) AND ste.TestingRework = 0) steR
    ON steR.TestingTestPackageNumber = td.TestPackageNumber AND steR.ActivityType = 41 AND td.ECT != "D"

LEFT JOIN (SELECT ste.ActivityType, ste.TestingTestPackageNumber, 1 AS InstalledHydro
            FROM `Job1111`.SubsTesting ste
            JOIN `Job1111`.SubmissionStatus ss
                ON ss.ActivityRowId = ste.ID AND ss.ActivityType = 42 AND ss.fk_ActivityStatus IN (5,12) AND ste.TestingRework = 0) steH
    ON steH.TestingTestPackageNumber = td.TestPackageNumber AND steH.ActivityType = 42 AND td.ECT != "D"

LEFT JOIN (SELECT ste.ActivityType, ste.TestingTestPackageNumber, 1 AS InstalledClientTurnover
            FROM `Job1111`.SubsTesting ste
            JOIN `Job1111`.SubmissionStatus ss
                ON ss.ActivityRowId = ste.ID AND ss.ActivityType = 43 AND ss.fk_ActivityStatus IN (5,12) AND ste.TestingRework = 0) steC
    ON steC.TestingTestPackageNumber = td.TestPackageNumber AND steC.ActivityType = 43 AND td.ECT != "D"

GROUP BY td.BidID
');

### Build Main Query ###
SET @GetQuery = CONCAT('
QUERY REMOVED DUE TO BODY SIZE LIMIT
');



### Execute NON Prep Queries ###
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Job1111`.`TempTrackerDetailsPipe`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `Job1111`.`TempTrackerDetailsPipe`(
INDEX `TempPipeTD1` (`BidID` ASC),
INDEX `TempPipeTD2` (`PipingActivityType` ASC, `ECT` ASC),
INDEX `TempPipeTD3` (`ECT` ASC)
)
SELECT min(ID) AS ID, BidID, sum(TakeOffQuantity) AS TakeOffQuantity, sum(EstimatedHours) AS EstimatedHours, ECT, PipingActivityType
FROM`Job1111`.`trackerDetails`
GROUP BY BidID;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSE`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSE`(
INDEX `TempPipeCSE1` (`fk_BidIDAssigned` ASC, `PSAActivityID` ASC)
)
SELECT ss.PSAActivityID, ss.fk_BidIDAssigned, (COALESCE(ErectionLengthSpool1,0) + COALESCE(ErectionLengthSpool2,0) + COALESCE(ErectionLengthSpool3,0) + COALESCE(ErectionLengthSpool4,0) + COALESCE(ErectionLengthSpool5,0) + COALESCE(ErectionLengthSpool6,0) + COALESCE(sme.MiscQuantity,0)) AS InstalledQuantity
FROM `Job1111`.SubmissionStatus ss
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsErection 
    ON ss.ActivityType = 11 AND ss.ActivityRowId = ID AND ErectionRework = 0
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.`TempTrackerDetailsPipe` td
    ON td.BidID = ss.fk_BidIDAssigned 
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsMisc sme
    ON sme.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 91 AND td.PipingActivityType = "PE" AND sme.MiscRework = 0
WHERE ss.fk_ActivityStatus IN (5,12)
AND ss.ActivityType IN (11,91)
HAVING InstalledQuantity > 0;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSB`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSB`(
INDEX `TempPipeCSB1` (`fk_BidIDAssigned` ASC, `PSAActivityID` ASC)
)
SELECT ss.PSAActivityID, ss.fk_BidIDAssigned, (COALESCE(BoltUpQuantity,0) + COALESCE(smb.MiscQuantity,0)) AS InstalledQuantity
FROM `Job1111`.SubmissionStatus ss
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsBoltUp 
    ON ss.ActivityType = 21 AND ss.ActivityRowId = ID AND BoltUpRework = 0
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.`TempTrackerDetailsPipe` td
    ON td.BidID = ss.fk_BidIDAssigned           
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsMisc smb
    ON smb.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 91 AND td.PipingActivityType = "BU" AND smb.MiscRework = 0
WHERE ss.fk_ActivityStatus IN (5,12)
AND ss.ActivityType IN (21,91)
HAVING InstalledQuantity > 0;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSW`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSW`(
INDEX `TempPipeCSW1` (`fk_BidIDAssigned` ASC, `PSAActivityID` ASC)
)
SELECT ss.PSAActivityID, ss.fk_BidIDAssigned, (COALESCE(WeldPercentCompleted,0) + COALESCE(smw.MiscQuantity,0)) AS InstalledQuantity
FROM `Job1111`.SubmissionStatus ss
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsWeld
    ON ss.ActivityType = 22 AND ss.ActivityRowId = ID AND WeldRework = 0
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.`TempTrackerDetailsPipe`td
    ON td.BidID = ss.fk_BidIDAssigned 
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsMisc smw
    ON smw.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 91 AND td.PipingActivityType = "W"AND smw.MiscRework = 0
WHERE ss.fk_ActivityStatus IN (5,12)
AND ss.ActivityType IN (22,91)
HAVING InstalledQuantity > 0;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSC`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSC`(
INDEX `TempPipeCSC1` (`fk_BidIDAssigned` ASC, `PSAActivityID` ASC)
)
SELECT ss.PSAActivityID, ss.fk_BidIDAssigned, (COALESCE(WeldPercentCompleted,0) + COALESCE(smc.MiscQuantity,0)) AS InstalledQuantity
FROM `Job1111`.SubmissionStatus ss
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsWeld
    ON ss.ActivityType = 23 AND ss.ActivityRowId = ID AND WeldRework = 0
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.`TempTrackerDetailsPipe`td
    ON td.BidID = ss.fk_BidIDAssigned 
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsMisc smc
    ON smc.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 91 AND td.ECT != "D" AND td.PipingActivityType = "CUT" AND smc.MiscRework = 0
WHERE ss.fk_ActivityStatus IN (5,12)
AND ss.ActivityType IN (23,91)
HAVING InstalledQuantity > 0;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Job1111`.`TempPipeCST`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `Job1111`.`TempPipeCST`(
INDEX `TempPipeCST1` (`fk_BidIDAssigned` ASC, `PSAActivityID` ASC)
)
SELECT ss.PSAActivityID, ss.fk_BidIDAssigned, (COALESCE(TrimQuantity,0) + COALESCE(smt.MiscQuantity,0)) AS InstalledQuantity
FROM `Job1111`.SubmissionStatus ss
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsTrim
    ON ss.ActivityType IN (30,31,33,34,35,39) AND ss.ActivityRowId = ID AND TrimRework = 0
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.`TempTrackerDetailsPipe` td
    ON td.BidID = ss.fk_BidIDAssigned
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsMisc smt
    ON smt.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 91 AND td.ECT = "T" AND td.PipingActivityType IN ("V","Plug","HpLp","Other","Blind")AND smt.MiscRework = 0
WHERE ss.fk_ActivityStatus IN (5,12)
AND ss.ActivityType IN (30,31,33,34,35,39,91)
HAVING InstalledQuantity > 0;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSSU`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSSU`(
INDEX `TempPipeCSSU1` (`fk_BidIDAssigned` ASC, `PSAActivityID` ASC)
)
SELECT ss.PSAActivityID, ss.fk_BidIDAssigned, (COALESCE(SupportQuantity,0) + COALESCE(smssu.MiscQuantity,0)) AS InstalledQuantity
FROM `Job1111`.SubmissionStatus ss
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsSupports
    ON ss.ActivityType = 32 AND ss.ActivityRowId = ID AND SupportRework = 0
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.`TempTrackerDetailsPipe` td
    ON td.BidID = ss.fk_BidIDAssigned
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsMisc smssu
    ON smssu.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 91 AND td.PipingActivityType = "S" AND smssu.MiscRework = 0
WHERE ss.fk_ActivityStatus IN (5,12)
HAVING InstalledQuantity > 0;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSD`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSD`(
INDEX `TempPipeCSD` (`fk_BidIDAssigned` ASC, `PSAActivityID` ASC)
)
SELECT ss.PSAActivityID, ss.fk_BidIDAssigned, (COALESCE(DemoQuantity,0) + COALESCE(smd.MiscQuantity,0)) AS InstalledQuantity
FROM `Job1111`.SubmissionStatus ss
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsDemo
    ON ss.ActivityType IN (50,51,52,53,59) AND ss.ActivityRowId = ID
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.`TempTrackerDetailsPipe` td
    ON td.BidID = ss.fk_BidIDAssigned
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.SubsMisc smd
    ON smd.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 91 AND td.ECT = "D" AND smd.MiscRework = 0
WHERE ss.fk_ActivityStatus IN (5,12)
AND ss.ActivityType IN (50,51,52,53,59,91)
HAVING InstalledQuantity > 0;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSM`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `Job1111`.`TempPipeCSM`(
INDEX `TempPipeCSM` (`fk_BidIDAssigned` ASC, `PSAActivityID` ASC)
)
SELECT ss.PSAActivityID, ss.fk_BidIDAssigned, MiscQuantity AS InstalledQuantity
FROM `Job1111`.SubmissionStatus ss
LEFT JOIN `Job1111`.`TempTrackerDetailsPipe` td
    ON td.BidID = ss.fk_BidIDAssigned 
JOIN `Job1111`.SubsMisc sm
    ON ss.ActivityType = 91 AND ss.ActivityRowId = sm.ID AND td.PipingActivityType = "MISC"  AND td.ECT != "D" AND sm.MiscRework = 0
WHERE ss.fk_ActivityStatus IN (5,12);


### Prepare Queries to execute ###
PREPARE BuildTempQuery1 FROM @TempQuery1;
PREPARE BuildTempQuery2 FROM @TempQuery2;
PREPARE BuildGetQuery FROM @GetQuery;

### Execute Prep Queries ###
EXECUTE BuildTempQuery1;
EXECUTE BuildTempQuery2;
EXECUTE BuildGetQuery;


### Deallocate Execute Querys and Tables###
DEALLOCATE PREPARE BuildTempQuery1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE BuildTempQuery2;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE BuildGetQuery;


END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I can tell you with all confidence that execution does not proceed until the temp table is ready for use, so it's not a timing issue.  MySQL 5.1 would throw a *warning* (not an error) if you used `DROP ... IF EXISTS` but that should have been fixed long ago and even then it was only a warning.  Perhaps the issue is that you're triggering a bug related to this by using `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ...` instead of the expected (and safer) `DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS ...`.  Does that make any difference?

Comment: Unrelated, it's not clear why you're concatenating values into your prepared statement. It seems like `?` placeholders and `EXECUTE stmt USING @var1, @var2, @var3, ...` would be more correct, safe, etc.  Or at least using the built-in `QUOTE()` function to properly escape the values and handle nulls properly.

Comment: @Michael you are absolutely correct on the "safer" usage of parameters instead of blindly concacting variables into a string.   The primary reason for atill doing it this ways was it was a simpler prototyping method then manafing 20+ question marks correctly... in addition to this stored procedure only recieves calls from other stored procedures with hard coded paramaters and twice escaped user parameters by this point.  YES, not "correct" ,  but not as open as it appears out of context.   Was waiting for someone to call that out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stored procedure is perfectly sound.  Except for one item.   Due to the fact that some prepared statements use Temp tables made by other prepared statements.  Care needs to be taken to Prepare AND EXECUTE the statements in the right order.

**Change This**

```
### Prepare Queries to execute ###
PREPARE BuildTempQuery1 FROM @TempQuery1;
PREPARE BuildTempQuery2 FROM @TempQuery2;
PREPARE BuildGetQuery FROM @GetQuery;

### Execute Prep Queries ###
EXECUTE BuildTempQuery1;
EXECUTE BuildTempQuery2;
EXECUTE BuildGetQuery;


### Deallocate Execute Querys and Tables###
DEALLOCATE PREPARE BuildTempQuery1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE BuildTempQuery2;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE BuildGetQuery;
```

**To This**

```
### Prepare Pass 1 Queries to execute ###
PREPARE BuildTempQuery1 FROM @TempQuery1;
PREPARE BuildTempQuery2 FROM @TempQuery2;

### Execute Pass 1 Queries ###
EXECUTE BuildTempQuery1 ;
EXECUTE BuildTempQuery2 ;


### Prepare Pass 2 Queries to execute ###
PREPARE BuildGetQuery FROM @GetQuery;

### Execute Pass 2 Queries ###
EXECUTE BuildGetQuery;



### Deallocate Execute Querys and Tables###
DEALLOCATE PREPARE BuildTempQueryER;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE BuildTempQueryERT;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE BuildGetQuery;
```

**Explanation**

The reason this is needed, is since "BuildGetQuery" is looking for the Temp Table created by "BuildTempQuery1".  It must exist BEFORE PREPARE of BuildGetQuery.

The mistake was thinking the "Do these tables exist?" check performed during the execution of "BuildGetQuery" where looking for tables made in  BuildTempQuery1 and BuildTempQuery1 happen at EXECUTE and not at PREPARE.
Turns out this check happens at PREPARE of "BuildGetQuery".  Meaning the Temp queries need to first be executed.

The one peace I'm missing is where in the MySQL documentation this reality is explained/demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see your code is that you want a query like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `database`.`temp_table` AS
SELECT user_id, name, address
FROM user
WHERE user_id = 3829;
ALTER TABLE `database`.`temp_table` 
ADD INDEX `index_name` (`user_id` ASC);
```

To be stored in a `session variable` using a `style` like this:

```
SET @session_variable = CONCAT('
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `database`.`temp_table` AS
    SELECT user_id, name, address
    FROM user
    WHERE user_id = 3829;
    ALTER TABLE `database`.`temp_table` 
    ADD INDEX `index_name` (`user_id` ASC);
');
```

But the proper way to do the `style` you want is this:

```
SET @session_variable = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `database`.`temp_table` AS ');
SET @session_variable = CONCAT(@session_variable, 'SELECT user_id, name, address ');
SET @session_variable = CONCAT(@session_variable, 'FROM user ');
SET @session_variable = CONCAT(@session_variable, 'WHERE user_id = 3829; ');
SET @session_variable = CONCAT(@session_variable, 'ALTER TABLE `database`.`temp_table` ');
SET @session_variable = CONCAT(@session_variable, 'ADD INDEX `index_name` (`user_id` ASC);');
```

or like this:

```
SET @session_variable = CONCAT(
    'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `database`.`temp_table` AS ',
    'SELECT user_id, name, address ',
    'FROM user ',
    'WHERE user_id = 3829; ',
    'ALTER TABLE `database`.`temp_table` ',
    'ADD INDEX `index_name` (`user_id` ASC); '
);
```

I would like to suggest that you read about `Prepared Statement` for `MySQL` in here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Hope I can help, cheers.

Comment: With all due respect, what on earth are you talking about friend?  No, no, very very much no! Why on earth would I wan't to waste all that time and effort building a session variable by concatenating each individual line appended to its self.   I'm not sure at all where you got the idea this question had anything to do with "styling"  My layout of my statement is entirely just for human readability.  The prepare couldn't care less about the space or carriage returns as long as the string is systematically correct.  I appreciate your effort, but so much no and misunderstanding in your answer..

Comment: What I am talking about is the way you `assign` the values for `@TempQuery1 `, `@TempQuery2`, and `@GetQuery` MySQL's engine does not read a multi-line concatenation like that. That's all

Comment: That is incorrect..  It does indeed read them.  I have used them many times before.  As well as mentioned above to great length that each of these prepared statements do in fact work if not ran all at the same time is all..

Comment: Okay then, I suggest that you need to test those sub-queries really returns the correct result set for it's parent query. I can understand the difference in coding and syntax

Comment: Again thanks for the input.  But that has also already been tested, described, and demonstrated above as not the issue.